# Tiny fuzzy pixelated discoloration on menu

Tags: css

This seems to be a problem in IE only. Chrome and firefox seem to work fine.

I am using IE11

I noticed in the menu there is a little tiny tiny gray fuzziness on the last menu item. Removing the border-radius resolves it, but I would prefer to keep it.

The curve around item 1 seems fine, where as the curve around item 5 has a slight discoloration protruding from the curve.

Also I realize the overall structure is less than ideal, but this is how it is currently more or less set up. I would prefer not having to change the html

```css
.navigation{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}



.navigation > li >a{
    border-right:1px solid white;
    background-color: rgb(0,68,106);
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 4px 6px 4px 6px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-top-left-radius:8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:8px;
}

.navigation ul{
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:0px;
    list-style-type:none;
}

.navigation ul li{
    display:inline-block;
}

.navigation ul li a{
    border-right:1px solid white;
    background-color: rgb(0,68,106);
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 4px 6px 4px 6px;
    display:inline-block;    
}

.navigation ul li:last-child a{
    border-top-right-radius:8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:8px;
}
```

```html
<ul class= "navigation">
    <li><a href="#">item 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">item 5</a></li>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule is causing the problem, and you don't seem to need it.  You can probably just remove it.

```
.navigation ul li a{
    border-right:1px solid white;
}
```

```css
.navigation{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}



.navigation > li >a{
    border-right:1px solid white;
    background-color: rgb(0,68,106);
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 4px 6px 4px 6px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-top-left-radius:8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:8px;
}

.navigation ul{
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:0px;
    list-style-type:none;
}

.navigation ul li{
    display:inline-block;
}

.navigation ul li a{
    /* this is messing you up */
    /* border-right:1px solid white; */
    background-color: rgb(0,68,106);
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 4px 6px 4px 6px;
    display:inline-block;    
}

.navigation ul li:last-child a{
    border-top-right-radius:8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:8px;
}
```

```html
<ul class= "navigation">
    <li><a href="#">item 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">item 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That is a weird behaviour ! Any idea why IE11 would react this way ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess it's because the background color is being drawn behind the border.  Normally, that's fine.  But on an anti-aliased curve, the background can leak through.  Imagine a particular pixel is 50% within the curve.  It's blended to 50% dark blue, and then blended 50% to white.  That leaves 25% intensity dark blue for that pixel on the outside edge of the border.